# Complex Hessian outputs don't match

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $\Omega:=\{(x_1,y_1,z_2,\bar z_2)\;:\;\underbrace{y_1-f(z_2,\bar z_2)+g(z_2,\bar z_2)}_{=:r(x_1,y_1,z_2,\bar z_2)}<0\}\subset\Bbb C^2$ (we confuse consciously $\Bbb C$ with $\Bbb R^2$)
where $f(z_2,\bar z_2):=-2x_2^2+y_2^2$ and $g$ is a real polynomial expression in $z_2,\bar z_2$ whose monomials are of degree $\ge3$.

We define $M:=\partial\Omega$, it's a real hypersurface.
Let $z_0=0\in\Bbb C^2$. If my computations are right, the hessian matrix of $r$ in $z_0=0$ is
$$
\operatorname{hess}_{r(0)}=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac32 & 0 & \frac12 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac12 & 0 & \frac32 
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Thus the Levi matrix of $r$ is

$$
L_{r(0)}=
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac12
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
and being the Levi form of $M$ in $z_0=0$ $L_M(0):={L_{r(0)}}_{|T_0^{\Bbb C}M}$ by definition, we have that $L_M(0)=\frac12$ (it's a $1\times1$ matrix), in fact (up to holomorphic coordinate change) we are allowed to think at $T_0^{\Bbb C}M$ as $\{(0,z_2)\;,\;z_2\in\Bbb C\}\simeq\Bbb C$.

Thus the Levi form of $M$ works as follows: given $z:=(0,z_2)\in T_0^{\Bbb C}M$, we have that $L_M(0)(z,z)=\frac12z_2^2$.

In particular if we take $z=e_2=(0,1)$, we get $L_M(0)(e_2,e_2)=\frac12$.

My problem comes here: if we use the well known formula
$$
L_{r(0)}(u,u)=\frac12[\operatorname{hess}_{r(0)}(u,u)+\operatorname{hess}_{r(0)}(iu,iu)]
$$
since
$$
\operatorname{hess}_{r(0)}(e_2,e_2):=
(0,1,\bar 0,\bar1)\operatorname{hess}_{r(0)}\left(\begin{matrix}
0\\
1\\
\bar0\\
\bar1
\end{matrix}\right)=4
$$
and similarly 
$
\operatorname{hess}_{r(0)}(ie_2,ie_2)=i^2+i^2=-2$
I would obtain
$L_M(0)(e_2,e_2)=1\neq\frac12$.

I suppose $1/2$ is right, $1$ is wrong, because the book writes so.

Where did I got wrong?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a misunderstanding: the quadratic form defined by the hessian matrix is to be taken divided by $2$ because we think at it as the quadratic part of the Taylor series. Hence the $4-2=2$ above becomes $1$ and all adds up!